# cannot send the string into INSERT query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

i have json as input

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://example.com/products.html');
$items = json_decode($page, true);
```

if i put echo $page; i get smth like this

```
{
"productlist":[
{
"id":"1",
"cat":"milk",
"prod_name":"happy milk",
"img_url":"http://example.com/milk.jpg"},
{
"id":"2",
"cat":"bread",
"prod_name":"black bread",
"img_url":"http://example.com/bread.jpg"},
```

then, i want to put it into MySQL DB

```
foreach($items['productlist'] as $item) {
$id = $item['id'];
$cat = $item['cat'];
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table (id, cat) VALUES ($id, $cat)")  or die(mysql_error());
}
```

at this stage i get nothing. if i modify code into

```
foreach($items['productlist'] as $item) {
$id = $item['id'];
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table (id) VALUES ($id)")  or die(mysql_error());
}
```

i get the table in DB filled - i have two rows with prod id. Ok, i want to insert into table the $cat = food

```
foreach($items['productlist'] as $item) {
$id = $item['id'];
$cat = 'food';
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table (id, cat) VALUES ($id, $cat)")  or die(mysql_error());
}
```

yet this does not work,  i get null result. but if i modify query into

```
foreach($items['productlist'] as $item) {
$id = $item['id'];
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table (id, cat) VALUES ($id, 'food')")  or die(mysql_error());
}
```

i get the result i seek for - tho rows in table, filled with id and cat

```
id   cat
1    food
2    food
```

does anyone know how to send string value into insert query via variable?

Comment: You could use prepared statements against possible SQL injection attacks since you use MySQLi already. This also would save you in single quote issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't work because `cat` is a `String` field, need to be between quotes `'...'`. try this :

```
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table (id, cat) VALUES ($id, '$cat')")  or die(mysql_error());
```

or this :

```
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table (id, cat) VALUES ($id, ".$cat.")")  or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest you to learn how to use prepared statements, as you are getting your strings outside of your code (it may contain some mysql injections).

To answer your question, you need to put some quotes around the variable you want to put in your query as it is a string, so mysql can interpret it correctly

```
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table (id, cat) VALUES ($id, '$cat')")  or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table (id, cat) VALUES ($id, ".mysql_real_escape_string($cat).")")  or die(mysql_error());`